# SqlConnection with Parallel programming

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

This is my existing code which save some data to several tables

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString"))
{
   DoWork1(conn);
   DoWork2(conc);
   DoWork3(conn);
}
```

In order to speed my code up so i try to get .net TPL support and i rehanged my code as below

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnString"))
{
   ParallelOptions pw = new ParallelOptions();
   pw.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

   Parallel.Invoke(pw,()=> DoWork1(conn),()=> DoWork2(conc),()=> DoWork3(conn));
}
```

But this throws me an Internal connection fatal error exception from the ExecuteNonQuery() method in my data access layer.Is my parallel approach is wrong?

Comment: "Is my parallel approach is wrong?" - quite possibly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are ways it could *potentially* be made to work using [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - but I would suggest a different approach. (I don't know whether MARS supports using the same connection across multiple threads, even though it allows multiple concurrent operations.)

Instead of trying to reuse one connection in all the parallel tasks, make each task open (and close) a connection for itself, and let connection pooling handle the efficiency side of that. That's general best practice in .NET whether you're using parallelism or not: open the connection, do some work, close the connection.

Comment: thank you sir for your quick response .I will try the second approach .(open and close the connection once per operation)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment but it seems I can answer.
That is a bit strange
Anyway my comment was that temporary tables are per connection, so opening a new connection means you cannot see the temporary tables created by the other task.

Global temporary tables might be the answer but you either have to
a) use a single global temp table and partition the data using some key
b) use uniquely named tables which means dynamic sql

All a bit of a mess really